# Aligning group labels in matplotlib / pie

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to align the top group levels in a stacked donut chart - so that that lables are inside the pie segment AND follow the curve of the pie -- as opposed to being horizontal?

In my example - top right "This is a long group lable" (yes I spelled it wrong) -- can this be inside the outer segment and following the curve of the segment?

```
import numpy as py
import seaborn as sns


group_names=['This is a long group lable', 'groupB', 'groupC']

group_size=[1,1,1]

subgroup_names=['This is a long sub group label', 'Label 2', 'label 3', 'Label 4', 'Label 5','Label 6', 'Label 7', 'Label 8', 'Label 9']

subgroup_size=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
inner_name =["This is the inner label"]
inner_group=[1]

# Create colors
a, b, c, d = [plt.cm.Blues, plt.cm.Reds, plt.cm.Greens,plt.cm.Blues]
 
# Outer Ring (outside)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('equal')
mypie, _ = ax.pie(group_size, radius=5, labels=group_names,labeldistance=0.95, colors=[a(0.6), b(0.6), c(0.6)] )
plt.setp( mypie, width=0.5, edgecolor='black')


# Label Ring (Inside)
mypie2, _ = ax.pie(subgroup_size, radius=4.5, labels=subgroup_names, labeldistance=0.9, colors=[a(0.5), a(0.5), a(0.5), b(0.5), b(0.5),b(0.5), c(0.5),c(0.5), c(0.5)])
plt.setp( mypie2, width=0.5, edgecolor='black')
plt.margins(0,0)
 
# 4th Ring (Inside)
mypie3, _ = ax.pie(subgroup_size, radius=4,  colors=[a(0.1), a(0.1), a(0.1), b(0.1), b(0.9),b(0.9), c(0.1),c(0.1), c(0.1)])
plt.setp( mypie3, width=0.5, edgecolor='black')
plt.margins(0,0)
     
# 3rd Ring (Inside)
mypie4, _ = ax.pie(subgroup_size, radius=3.5,  colors=[a(0.1), a(0.9), a(0.1), b(0.1), b(0.9),b(0.9), c(0.1),c(0.9), c(0.1)])
plt.setp( mypie4, width=0.5, edgecolor='black')
plt.margins(0,0)


# 2nd Ring (Inside)
mypie5, _ = ax.pie(subgroup_size, radius=3,  colors=[a(0.9), a(0.9), a(0.1), b(0.9), b(0.9),b(0.9), c(0.9),c(0.9), c(0.1)])
plt.setp( mypie5, width=0.5, edgecolor='black')
plt.margins(0,0)


# 1st Ring (Inside)
mypie6, _ = ax.pie(subgroup_size, radius=2.5,  colors=[a(0.9), a(0.9), a(0.9), b(0.9), b(0.9),b(0.9), c(0.9),c(0.9), c(0.1)])
plt.setp( mypie6, width=0.5, edgecolor='black')

# Inner rin Ring (Inside)
mypie7, _ = ax.pie(inner_group, radius=2,labels=inner_name, labeldistance=-0, colors=["black"])
plt.setp( mypie7, width=2, edgecolor='black')


plt.margins(0,0)


# show it
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official references, I tried many things. With the following code, you can set the text placement and angle of the annotation. I set the values manually through trial and error. You may be able to respond more programmatically.

```
# Libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make data: I have 3 groups and 7 subgroups
group_names = ['This is a long group lable', 'groupB', 'groupC']
group_size = [1,1,1]
group_angle = [-32, 90, 220]

subgroup_names=['This is a long sub group label', 'Label 2', 'label 3', 'Label 4', 'Label 5','Label 6', 'Label 7', 'Label 8', 'Label 9']
subgroup_size=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
subgroup_angle = [-70,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
# Create colors
a, b, c = [plt.cm.Blues, plt.cm.Reds, plt.cm.Greens]

# First Ring (outside)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('equal')
mypie, txts = ax.pie(group_size, radius=5, labels=group_names, startangle=0, labeldistance=0.97, colors=[a(0.6), b(0.6), c(0.6)] )
for txt,agl in zip(txts, group_angle):
    txt.set_ha('center')
    txt.set_va('center')
    txt.set_rotation(agl)
plt.setp(mypie, width=0.5, edgecolor='black')

# Second Ring (Inside)
mypie2, txts2 = ax.pie(subgroup_size, radius=4.5, labels=subgroup_names, labeldistance=0.95, colors=[a(0.5), a(0.5), a(0.5), b(0.5), b(0.5), b(0.5), c(0.5), c(0.5), c(0.5), c(0.5)])
for txt,agl in zip(txts2, subgroup_angle):
    txt.set_ha('center')
    txt.set_va('center')
    txt.set_rotation(agl)
plt.setp(mypie2, width=0.5, edgecolor='black')
plt.margins(0,0)

# show it
plt.show()
```

[image]